# Ruby on Rails next 3 months select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, select, date

I am making a form for my website which allows a user to select a date but only with the next 3 months.

I have read the rails docs on the `DateHelper` which is excellent but I can not seem to get a select dropdown with only the next 3 months in it, I can only display the next 12, does anyone know how to only show the next 3 months?

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can. You would be better off (from a UI standpoint) using jQuery's date selector http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/.

However, you'll need to validate that the date submitted is still valid on the backend even if you restrict on the frontend (because javascript validations are easily subverted).

```
def valid_date(date)
  return date <= Time.new + 3.months
end
```